# Memory error when derriving a value using sympy.solvers

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, spyder, numerical-methods

Hey i am trying to derrive a value 'b' from a few equations by using sympy.solvers.

a few values that not have been given here have been imported from an excel sheet

```
R = 0.287
cp = 1
cv = 0.714
kappa = cp/cv
v_r1 = 438.15
p_r1 = 2.264

b = Symbol('b')

for k in range(4):
    T1[k] = T1_c[k] + 273.15
    P2[k] = P1[k]*(epsilon**(kappa))
    T2[k] = T1[k]*(epsilon**(kappa-1))
    a[k] = P3[k]/P2[k]
    P4[k] = P3[k]
    T3[k] = a[k]*T2[k]
    W_i[k] = P_mi[k]*V_s[k]
    wi[k] = W_i[k]/((P1[k]*V1[k])/(R*T1[k]))

w12 = -cv*(T2[0]-T1[0])
w34 = cv*T1[0]*(kappa-1)*(epsilon**(kappa-1))*a[0]*(b-1)
w45 = cv*T1[0]*(((epsilon**(kappa-1))*a[0]*b)-(a[0]*(b**(kappa-1))))
expr1 = w34 + w45 - np.abs(w12) - wi[0]
b1 = solve((w34 + w45 - np.abs(w12) - wi[0]), b, quick=True, warn=True)
```

this is the error that is received after running the code:

```
   h.append(f.get((k,), K.zero))

MemoryError
```

does anyone have any tips or know if it possible to derrive b using this solver? any info would be really appreciated!!

Comment: It's not possible to answer this with the information provided. If you replace all the variables with symbols and that still reproduces the problem then you can rewrite the question like that.

Comment: So in other words, i have to put all the variables into the solve function without having them implicitly expressed in the other formula?

Comment: What I mean is that you have not presented your problem for stack overflow in such a way that other people can help you with it. I have no idea what `T1[0]`, `epsilon` etc are.

Comment: Oh okay i thought it would be more confusing to add the variables but i will insert my whole script then as those values were previously calculated, Thanks

Comment: The values that are not given come from an excell sheet

Comment: You need to simplify this: you are including unnecessary code but at the same time not including the necessary bits to allow someone to reproduce what you are seeing (what is `T`?). Include the minimum code needed to generate the expression you are passing to solve (use `repr` to get this) plus the code to define any symbols. It would also help just to show what the expression is.

Comment: Thanks @OscarBenjamin for redirecting me into posting clearer codes for the future! it truly is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question has a lot of undeclared variables, I just added the necessary declarations and some random values to get more insight.

My random parameters give an expression for `expr1` that looks like:

```
-42730504.6501296*b**0.400560224089636 + 1495543.03214645*b - 428340.625314184
```

for which sympy's solve gets into memory trouble.

As sympy try to find exact symbolic solutions, and we are dealing with imprecise floats, a better strategy seems to be to try to solve this numerically. Sympy has a function `lambdify` to convert its expressions to a function that can be used numerically.

`fb = lambdify(b, expr1, 'numpy')` converts expr1 to a function `fb(x)`, that now can be called as any normal python function. You could use it e.g. for plotting to see whether it makes sense, and where about it reaches zero.

I tried to call scipy's nonlinear solver, but he also didn't like the equation. `RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last ten iterations.` But maybe this is because my random numbers don't make sense. I suggest you try out with scipy's solve, and other of its [nonlinear solvers](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html).

As mentioned in the comments by @Oscar Benjamin, sympy also has a numerical solver, which *does* give a solution, although it is a complex number. (The documentation advices to give `nsolve` a complex number as initial value if you need a complex solution.) Sympy's `solve` and scipy's `fsolve` only search for real valued solutions.

It is unclear whether complex values are useful for the problem you are trying to solve, nor whether my simulation of the parameters makes any sense.

```py
from sympy import *
import random

R = 0.287
cp = 1
cv = 0.714
kappa = cp/cv
v_r1 = 438.15
p_r1 = 2.264

b = Symbol('b')

T1 = [None] * 4
T2 = [None] * 4
T3 = [None] * 4
P2 = [None] * 4
P4 = [None] * 4
a = [None] * 4
W_i = [None] * 4
wi = [None] * 4
P1 = [random.random() for _ in range(4)]
P3 = [random.random() for _ in range(4)]
T1_c = [random.random() for _ in range(4)]
P_mi = [random.random() for _ in range(4)]
V1 = [random.random() for _ in range(4)]
V_s = [random.random() for _ in range(4)]

epsilon = 0.0001

for k in range(4):
    T1[k] = T1_c[k] + 273.15
    P2[k] = P1[k]*(epsilon**(kappa))
    T2[k] = T1[k]*(epsilon**(kappa-1))
    a[k] = P3[k]/P2[k]
    P4[k] = P3[k]
    T3[k] = a[k]*T2[k]
    W_i[k] = P_mi[k]*V_s[k]
    wi[k] = W_i[k]/((P1[k]*V1[k])/(R*T1[k]))

w12 = -cv*(T2[0]-T1[0])
w34 = cv*T1[0]*(kappa-1)*(epsilon**(kappa-1))*a[0]*(b-1)
w45 = cv*T1[0]*(((epsilon**(kappa-1))*a[0]*b)-(a[0]*(b**(kappa-1))))
expr1 = w34 + w45 - Abs(w12) - wi[0]
print(expr1)
sol = nsolve(expr1, b, 1)
print(sol)

fb = lambdify(b, expr1, 'numpy')

from scipy.optimize  import fsolve
sol = fsolve(fb, 0)
```

Comment: You can also use SymPy's `nsolve` for numerical solutions `nsolve(expr, b, 1)` for your example gives `268.908831729817 + 5.2979914706174e-23⋅ⅈ`

Comment: Much appreciated. Makes the suse of this solver much clearer aswell! Thank you

Comment: it  is possible that a complex number is necesary for the solution so many thanks for that aswell @OscarBenjamin

Comment: The answer is approximate and has a tiny imaginary part that you should think of as being zero so that's a real root.